# Pushing to local phabricator with TortoiseHG produces Error

Tags: mercurial, phabricator

I want to push changes of a Mercurial Repository to Phabricator in our production.

What ever i try to do push or pull to the repository , it fails with the following command
***HTTP Error: 500 (Error 255: abort: potentially unsafe serve --stdio invocation: ['serve', '--stdio'])***

I am using Workbench and Tortoise for this.

Also note that this doesnt happen for any repository that is using GIT . This only occurs for mercurial Repositories.

Any idea on what configuration should i  change on phabricator or on my local repository so that this can work?

I tried pushing with tortoiseHG and with HG workbench to no avail. Still geting the same error. I also tried to allow HTTP pushes to phabricator from the deffusion setting.Still the same thing

Comment: i have managed to avoid this error by modifing a python function in the file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py . I added an extra letter to the exception and now it gets bypassed. Bit Now i get an error like HTTP Error 500:internal Server error.     i am starting to suspect a bug in mercurial here. As i stated previously the git repositories dont have such problems.

Comment: Bellow is the current error i get in the  apache logs and the versions of phabricator,arcanist etc..

Comment: [Mon Jan 22 10:17:08.621143 2024] [:error] [pid 28482] [client 192.168.100.122:10613] [2024-01-22 10:17:08] EXCEPTION: (Exception) Expected nonempty 'cmds' specification! at [<phabricator>/src/applications/diffusion/protocol/DiffusionMercurialWireProtocol.php:68]...


phabricator
    c9cc3832912f9c52ec1ea1397c062cc3f8ffc659 (Oct 9 2016) 
arcanist
    71132dbee0e2b585bdacd1481ef76eb210814139 (Oct 9 2016) 
phutil
    dd02a0817366bf78d7e468143fbac0e42db7d7c7 (Oct 9 2016)